# Windows Server 2003 Standard - how to access other pc's remotely

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-access, windows, windows-server-2003-r2

I'm a novice in the world of servers, and I'm about to install Windows Server 2003 Standard on a server box I have...However, I'm curious if there is a way to access the other PC's in my network remotely via the server (Windows XP Home and Windows 7 Home Premium)?  Like say, I'm at a friend's house, and I want to access my Win7 machine via the server, how do I do it?  Is it possible?  *Thanks!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Windows Home doesn't come with RDP, which is usually accessible by right clicking on "My Computer" , selecting "Properties" , and then click the "REmote" tab.   The server has RDP but since the Home editions cannot listen on port 3389, you cant remote desktop to them from that server.

Since RDP isn't available then your next best option is probably VNC, of which I believe [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) is the most convenient for a beginner.

Requires that you open port 5900 on your windows firewall plus your NAT router.

NOTE:  there is a newer [TightVNC-beta](http://www.tightvnc.com/announce-2.0beta1.php) that is out but I havent tried it.  It might be worth using.  The final version of 2.0 should be out any day now.